# Bouncy Castle C# API and NTRUEncrypt

Tags: encryption, .net

I want to play around with NTRUEncrypt and I found this [tweet](https://twitter.com/NTRUEncrypt/statuses/182677524927619073) that NTRUE is now part of bouncy castle.
But I cannot find any proof of the existence in the source code of the Bouncy Castle C# API, 
http://www.bouncycastle.org/csharp/

In the specifications http://www.bouncycastle.org/specifications.html, you can see the NTRUEngine. But this Engine is no part of the source code I have.

Some help?

Comment: It's probably only in the java version. The C# version of bouncycastle is lagging behind the java version in many places.